# PyODBC return error, but why?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2008, pyodbc

I try execute T-SQL query in two cases (i use Win7, python 3.2, MS SQL Server express 2008,pyodbc for python 3.2):

-case 1:

using MS SQL Server Management Studio i try to execute query:

```
USE master;CREATE DATABASE Sales ON (NAME = Sales_dat,FILENAME = 'C:\saledat.mdf',        SIZE = 10,    MAXSIZE = 50,    FILEGROWTH = 5 ) LOG ON ( NAME = Sales_log,    FILENAME = 'C:\salelog.ldf',    SIZE = 5MB,    MAXSIZE = 25MB, FILEGROWTH = 5MB );
```

it return successful result

-case 2:

```
import pyodbc
cxnn=pyodbc.connect('DSN=SERVER;UID=sa;PWD=password')
cur=cxnn.cursor()
cur.execute("USE master;CREATE DATABASE Sales ON (NAME = Sales_dat,FILENAME = 'C:\saledat.mdf',    SIZE = 10,    MAXSIZE = 50,    FILEGROWTH = 5 ) LOG ON ( NAME = Sales_log,    FILENAME = 'C:\salelog.ldf',    SIZE = 5MB,    MAXSIZE = 25MB, FILEGROWTH = 5MB );")
cxnn.commit()
```

but after running code i receive error

```
 pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

If i run the code without

```
cxnn.commit()
```

i have receive no error. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons I don't quite understand, setting autocommit to be true seems to fix the issue. Please note that escaping the backslashes is still required.

Autocommit can be set in two ways:

```
cxnn=pyodbc.connect('DSN=SERVER;UID=sa;PWD=password', autocommit=True)
```

Or:

```
cxnn=pyodbc.connect('DSN=SERVER;UID=sa;PWD=password')
cxnn.autocommit = True
```

Once that's done, creating the cursor and executing the query should then run as expected:

```
cur=cxnn.cursor()
cur.execute("USE master;CREATE DATABASE Sales ON (NAME=Sales_dat, FILENAME='C:\\saledat.mdf', SIZE=10, MAXSIZE=50, FILEGROWTH=5) LOG ON (NAME=Sales_log, FILENAME='C:\\salelog.ldf', SIZE=5MB, MAXSIZE=25MB, FILEGROWTH=5MB );")
```

Comment: No, i try your string (with escape backslashes), but again receive error pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!'). And if i run the code without commit() all is work without error. But without commit i can not save changes to DB

Comment: Have you been able to get this code to work using autocommit?

Comment: yes, i confirm, it work with autocommit, thanks. But why it works only with autocommit?

Comment: That is a good question. Perhaps it would be worth asking the PyODBC dev?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I simply needed to upgrade pyodbc for it to work.

```
pip install --upgrade pyodbc
```